# Flask-admin get data sen

Tags: database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Task: I would like to catch data sending by flask-admin to database after fill in forms in admin panel.

I have overridden default User view as follows:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class UserModelView(ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_active and current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.has_role("admin")

    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_accessible():
            return redirect(url_for("admin.index"))
```

All modifications on admin panel after save are going to database (flask-sqlalchemy) and it works fine.
Now I would like to catch the data that is sending, for example:
I have changed username from X to Y and click "save".
I want to catch that piece of information with username = "Y" sending to database.
In docs I saw that there is method:

```
 on_model_change(form, model, is_created)[source]

    Perform some actions before a model is created or updated.
```

So I think this is a place where I should put my code, but question is, how can I get that data sending from there to database?

Normally, when I fill in something on web, its form defined by me so I just use data from this form, but here its defined by flask-admin and I have to idea how to access there.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a `form` object in the `on_model_change` method which contains all the fields and their data received from the client. Did you try accessing it? Also `model` object is your `User` instance with the attributes already filled from the `form` data. You can use it too.

Comment: That's that - I used *model* arg, assigned there User class and got attributes as you mentioned. 
Thanks